# Resize and convert image to greyscale in R

Tags: r

What is the most efficient way to resize and convert images to greyscale in R. Currently I use the convert command on Linux as follows:

```
convert Slide3.JPG -resize 600X400\! -colorspace Gray img3.JPG
```

I want the resizing to ignore the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `imager` package and do:

```
library(imager)
z = load.image("Slide3.JPG")
z = grayscale(z)
y = resize(z, size_x = 600, size_y = 400)
save.image(im = y, "img3.JPG")
```