# Convert rgb image into grayscale, grey() is not working

Tags: r, arrays, image, image-processing

This loads the images

```
library(OpenImageR)
library(abind)

path = list.files(".../df",".jpg", full.names = T)
```

This is a loop to read all images

```
im=lapply(path, readImage)
```

This code to read all images as an array

```
  com <- do.call(abind,im)
```

The outcome is 416X600X30 for 10 images

The outcome that I need 416X600X10

This code to convert image into grayscale, but it does not work

```
 grayscale <- gray(seq(0, 1, length = 255))

image(com[,,1], xaxt='n', yaxt='n', col=grayscale)
```

The dimension is still 416X600X30

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/45774404/680068

Comment: What packages are you using? readImage function?

Comment: There is no package named readImage, could you share a link? And grayscale is an object not a function?

Comment: @zx8754EOpenImageR package

Comment: @zx8754I tried rgb_2gray; it gives this error:Error in rgb_2gray(com) : 
  The 'RGB_image' parameter must be a 3-dimensional array!

Comment: @user20003920, In the next days I'll modify the error messages of the [OpenImageR](https://github.com/mlampros/OpenImageR) package because the current ones might not return the exact requirements for an input image. If you receive this error then the image has to be 3-dimensional and the 3rd dimension should be equal to 3 (for instance an RGB image of dimensions 416 x 600 x 3)